# freemarker.runtime - Template processing error: "No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"

Tags: tags, spring-security, freemarker

Spring-security:3.0.2
Freemarker:2.3.19

I want to use springSecurity tags in freemarker, but it throws this errors:

[16 14:10:46,349 ERROR] [btpool0-0] freemarker.runtime - Template processing error: "No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"

No mapping defined for http://www.springframework.org/security/tags

### The problematic instruction:

==> assignment: security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] [on line 1, column 1 in macro/header.ftl]
 in user-directive page.bodytemplate [on line 6, column 1 in items.ftl]

ftl:
    <#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you configured your web.xml or your configuration.xml(which ever you use)? It looks like a mapping issue to me .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, I just config pom.xml.

Comment: I don't think that's all to configuring spring security in pom.xml. Use this link here :http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/ . It shows you how to configure pom.xml with spring security.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, Thanks for your reply, I have config these, that's not useful for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a tag library which you want to download contains the tag           `org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AclTag`.
The last version of Spring Security taglibs (which had this class) was the 2.0.7 release, hence the problem.

You can change you spring to 2.0 version. Or you can download security.tld from https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-security/branches/spring-2.5-integration-branch/taglibs/src/main/resources/META-INF/security.tld and use it on freemarker template like this: `<#assign security=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tlds/security.tld"] />`

By the way I really don't understand why http://www.springframework.org/security/tags doesn't work... I have tried to use it like you, and I have faced the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I use "<#assign security=JspTaglibs["/WEB-INF/tlds/security.tld"] />" to fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

if the problems happen with tomcat7-maven-plugin and not with jetty-maven-plugin  you most likely suffer from the not fully initialized servlet context of tomcat7.

Instead of "tomcat:run", do "tomcat:run-war"

the latter makes sure that your web app is (almost) fully being build and bootstrapped, like having jars in /WEB-INF/libs. freemarker's scanning logic for tlds will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when switched to run-jetty-run maven module.
Module jetty:run didn't had this error.

This helped me:

1. Download spring-security.tld file and put it in webapp/WEB-INF/tld folder
2. Add this code to web.xml:

   ```
   <jsp-config>
       <taglib>
           <taglib-uri>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</taglib-uri>
           <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-security.tld</taglib-location>
       </taglib> 
   </jsp-config>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work has to do with the Servlet container (and maybe the spec). If you're associating taglibs by the namespace it will only do that automatically if the JAR is in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

If you move the spring-security-taglibs.jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder, it will work.